# Remote IP scan detected

Tags: network

I would appreciate if you take some time to go over issue I am facing. On my laptop I have windows 7 installed, I am using ESET Smart Security 5.2.9.1. As I work 9 hours day online I am seeing a message remote IP scan detected by ESET notification in red, not in green. Which is giving me an idea that someone is going through the data in my PC or seeing what I am doing and also being successful at it.

Please tell me how to stop as I though that was the best software I am using please recommend settings to prevent that or suggest buying any software where this can stop which isn't a problem.

Comment: "You're on the Internet, something will always attempt to attack you." - So, don't worry about it. Nobody is in your system, it's just some bots/scriptkiddies are trying to scan your ports or something like that.

Comment: I understand and appreciate you used your valuable time to answer this but the company I am working for provided me a dashboard to log into and I am also connected to them by g-talk. Also they have advised us several time that they can actually takes pics of what are doing beside our work since I am a home based agent, can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: @SharjeelBinNasir When they didn't install any monitoring software on your computer, they are likely bluffing. When they did, it's a case for http://workplace.stackexchange.com because it's not a technical issue but one about the relationship between you and your employer.

Comment: I understand, and agree with you here, they are most likely bluffing, thanks for the extra insight about stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

Any system connected to the internet is going to get scanned, and often. If your system was behind a firewall which was set up to only allow outgoing connections then you would not be seeing these messages. This leads me to believe that you either have a direct internet connection or you are behind a firewall but it is set up to forward packets to your system.

The best thing you could do to protect your system would be to either put a firewall between your system and your internet connection, or if you already have one to configure it to only allow outgoing connections.

**EDIT:** Poster says his PC is directly connected to the internet

The main issue with your setup is that all operating systems have zero day vulnerabilities which could be used by an attacker to take over your system no matter what software firewall and antimalware software you are running. These are often integrated into automated software which scans the internet trying to infect as many systems as it can find, so even if you are extremely diligent about installing every single software patch you are vulnerable. The only way to reduce this risk would be to purchase a hardware firewall to protect your system.

Regarding your concerns regarding your employer it's unlikely that they've been able to install monitoring system behind your back, however monitoring software could have been installed as part of a wider software package, so if you were asked to install software on your system it is possible that it could be monitoring you. Also, java applets could hook into your camera, microphone, or browse your files. I'd say the likelihood of that being done is low if taken across all employers, however you have a better idea as you work for them. Plus they seem to have made statements to the effect that they are monitoring you, which could just be them joking but maybe not. If you are being monitored and you live in a place where there are employee laws that will protect you then it's a matter for law enforcement, if not then you need to take steps to protect yourself.

What I would do is either buy a second system and do employer work on that second system. You can physically disable any camera or microphone on it and as long as you keep it purely for work your employer will never see anything personal. If you cannot do that the other option would be to create a virtual system within your physical computer and use that for employer work. You can configure the virtual box to have absolutely no access to microphone or cameras on your physical system, and the virtualization will allow you to separate your personal and work data within one physical system. Just be sure to strictly limit the access from your work system to your personal system no matter what method you use.

Of course you could just tape over your mic and camera if you are worried about the physical surveillance aspect.

Comment: Yes, you are correct I am using a direct internet connection (USB Internet device) but I have allowed only certain program through firewall "Domain Profile": Windows firewall is on; Inbound connection that do not match a rule are blocked; Outbound connection that do not match a rule are allowed: Same goes for "private profile is active" and "Public profile".

Answer (score 1):

There are (tens|hundreds)thousands of people scanning the internet and (mi|bi)llions of instances of w0rms constantly trying to attack everything they can. Being directly connected to the internet is simply ***NOT SAFE***. Please.. I'm begging you go get at least a simple router, something to put between your computer and the internet.

Comment: Laptop mobile internet dongles are often advanced enough to qualify as a router. The WiFi of tablets and mobiles with crippleware/bloatware OSes are much larger concern than a properly patched laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar on machines with Norton Internet Security installed, even when behind a firewalled network. It continually warned the user that a remote connection attempt was attempted when this was simply the return TCP packet being received from the websites they've visited.